# What should I do to prevent cellulose from turning black?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

In my research on producing ethanol from grass, I have boiled 4g of grass in a beaker on a Bunsen burner with 30ml of sulfuric acid (bottle of 1 mol/l). However, within a few minutes the solution turned black and thus was burnt with release of smoke.

In my next attempt to try out this experiment this Monday, I want to make a 2.5 % sulfuric acid solution using a bottle of sulfuric acid with a concentration of 1 mol/l and add it to 4g of grass and boiling it for one hour.

What is your advice on this? Should I add a larger volume of sulfuric acid solution, and if so, how much?

Comment: Hi Tofighi, welcome to Chem.SE! Take the [tour], enjoy your stay! However it is frowned upon to ask multiple questions in one question. If you could split this question up, that would be nice! Thanks!

Comment: I hope it is specific now.

Comment: Because of the edit, it should go back into the reopen queue. Have patience and it should be reopened.